# how do I populate column C in an excel sheet based on the matches found in column B of another sheet?

Tags: python, excel, automation, openpyxl, data-analysis

so I have one excel workbook, namely **"test.xlsx"**

there are two sheets in it:

**bank** with the following data:

```
Name ID Leaves
-     1   0
-     3   0
-     2   0
-     4   0
```

**user** with the following data:

```
Name ID Leaves
-     1   5
-     2   10
-     3   15
```

when I run my script on this sheet I get a new file called **"ready.xls"** in that file I have the now-manipulated **bank** sheet with this output:

```
 Name ID Leaves
  -    1   5
  -    3   10
  -    2   15
  -    4   0
```

whereas what I want should be like this:

```
Name ID Leaves
 -    1   5
 -    3   15
 -    2   10
 -    4   0
```

I realize that despite ID column having same data in both sheets, the data in the **user** sheet is out of sync, and that is obviously causing the issue. I could fix by sorting/serializing first, but that's not ideal for my dataset. This script should cope with this irregularity and print desired results somehow. is this possible? any help would be highly appreciated.

Here's my code so far: https://pastebin.com/KYdWcqCD

PS: I'm making use of this library called [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/)

Comment: I don't have access to your code, can you post here? Also, if the value of ID `1` is 5 in `bank` and 10 in `user`, are you expecting it to be 15 in your new file?

Comment: my code is here in a pastebin: https://pastebin.com/KYdWcqCD

Comment: in the `bank` sheet, the `leaves` column is initally `0` for all the values of `ID` avilable in the `bank` sheet. so next. if the value of ID is `1` in `user` sheet and the `leave` column of the same sheet is, say `5` so it's initially `1=5` where `1` is `ID` and `5` is corresponding value in `leaves`. so I want the script to take that into account, and go to `bank` sheet and search for matching `ID` which in this case would be `1` so if it sees `1` it should automatically put `5` in the `leaves` column right  next to it and so on @Zac

Answer (score 0):

alright. so I got the problem fixed.

Turns out, my earlier intuition about the problem was correct all along. Earlier my code was putting all the `IDS` of `bank` sheet into a list called `IDS` and would check if any element of the `IDS` list would match with any element found in `IDS` column of `user` sheet, and then it would copy the `leaves` data from `user` to `bank without matching the`IDS`.

so I changed the whole structure of the script. I got `IDS` and `Leaves` from both sheets into two different lists. then I created a dictionary out of it with `keys=IDS` and `values=leaves` something like `mydict=1:5`. then I matched the `IDS` with `Keys` and for every correct match, I copied the corresponding `values` from the said dictionary. and voila! problem fixed.

PS: here's the link to updated code: https://pastebin.com/zdgD9bpv